# I want to connect local laravel application with ASW RDS

Tags: laravel-9, aws-rds-data-service

I am able to connect using MySQL Workbench using pem key but when I try to use same details in laravel env, I am getting below error

PHP Warning: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000.
amework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php on line 70.

WARN  PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php on line 46.